# Clojure and HBase: Format the result of HBase Scan to Clojure maps

Tags: java, clojure, hbase, clojure-java-interop

I have a function developed in Clojure to `scan` a HBase table:

```
(defn- ^Scan make-scan []
 (Scan. ))


(defn hscan [hbase tbl]
  (let [htbl (.getTable  (:connection hbase)  (. TableName valueOf tbl))
        scanner (.getScanner htbl (make-scan))
        results (mapv (fn preprocess-result [result]
                   result)
             scanner)]
    (println "Results: " results)))
```

And I call the function thus for a given HBase table name `lookup`:

```
(hscan @hbase "lookup")
```

PS: The `@hbase` holds the HBase configuration

I'm getting this as output:

```
Results: [
          #object[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result 0x16cf8438 keyvalues={Pepsi/A:Canada/1443095322877/Put/vlen=5/seqid=0, Pepsi/A:USA/1443095303916/Put/vlen=5/seqid=0}]
          #object[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result 0x3e5beab5 keyvalues={Wallmart/A:Canada/1443095361758/Put/vlen=5/seqid=0, Wallmart/A:USA/1443095349956/Put/vlen=5/seqid=0}]
         ]
```

And actually I have 2 rows in the HBase table:

```
 hbase(main):007:0> scan 'lookup'
 ROW                            COLUMN+CELL                                                                            
 Pepsi                         column=A:Canada,   timestamp=1443095322877, value=upc-b                                  
 Pepsi                         column=A:USA, timestamp=1443095303916, value=upc-a                                     
 Wallmart                      column=A:Canada, timestamp=1443095361758, value=upc-d                                  
 Wallmart                      column=A:USA, timestamp=1443095349956, value=upc-c                                     
 2 row(s) in 0.0790 seconds
```

Question is I want to format the result to produce a clojure map of the form:

```
{
  :Pepsi {:A {:USA "upc-a" :Canada "upc-b"}}
  :Wallmart {:A {:USA "upc-c" :Canada "upc-d"}}
}
```

And I'm lost on how to implement that. Kindly help me with this implementation

Thanks!

Comment: @zero323, Please can you point me in the right direction? Thanks